# Move Synology packages and ipkg applications to another volume

Tags: nas

I have just had a harddrive failing in RAID1 on my Synology DS412+, and since the drive is not available for replacement, I have upgraded to 3x 3TB plus one old 1TB (the one left in the old array). The 3x 3TB is now my "primary" volume, but since the applications are installed on the old array (the remaining 2TB, now degraded), I cannot use the applications.

The problem is not the Synology packages, but rather those installed using the ipkg package manager. How can I "transfer" those applications (if possible, all applications and their settings) to my new volume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is still asking himself this question four years later, then here is an answer provided by Andrew McLean : [Move Application Between Volumes](http://www.mcleanit.ca/blog/synology-move-application-volumes/)

> - Stop all your applications (Package Center > Installed > Action > Stop)

```
sudo /var/packages/[app_name]/scripts/start-stop-status stop
```

> - Move the app files from the old volume to the desired one (in this case from `volume1` to `volume2`)

```
sudo mv /volume1/\@appstore/[app_name] /volume2/\@appstore/
```

> - Delete the obsolete Symlink pointing at the old app path

```
sudo rm -fv /var/packages/[app_name]/target
```

> - Create a new Sim link pointing at the new, correct app path

```
sudo ln -s /volume2/\@appstore/[app_name] /var/packages/[app_name]/target
```

> - Reboot
>
> NB : Apps like Snapshot Replication, CrashPlan and DownloadStation had
>   to be uninstalled and reinstalled manually, but for the majority of
>   apps this should work.

[Experimental script](https://gist.github.com/nobodypb/fc3e70b535bcd95b5de7659d6fbda434) provided by Sebastian Ott

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it would be [preferable to include the essential parts of the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: But depending on the package you may loose the package specific data, e.g for ActiveBackup there is an additional folder: @ActiveBackup on the volume